# iPhone Simulator slow and jerky

Tags: ios-simulator

My problem is that when ever the iPhone has to push a view (like the keyboard) it takes a really long time (15+ seconds).

I never used to have this problem with the simulator, but after I updated xcode to 3.2.3, the simulator is almost un-usable for anything which requires a keyboard.

For example, on the simulator the springboard app (the one which stores your icons and has the search pane to the far left). When I scroll all the way over to the search, the keyboard pops up immediately but it takes a very long time for it to register any taps and the entire simulator becomes unresponsive.

This happens with any app.

Also, sometimes it can take a very long time for the keyboard to even show.

I'd really appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: I have a similar problem here. Scrolling around a `MKMapView` is glacially slow, far worse than it is on a real device. It's only this one machine, but, unfortunately, my primary workstation.

Comment: same here, upvoting this issue. i see it primarily in uitableviews and uiscrollviews, even in simple example code downloaded from the apple developer site. really really annoying. :(

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was being caused by the NSZombieEnabled flag. Try disabling that if you have it set and the MKMapView may come "back to life".

EDIT: Unfortunately my problem just came back, so the above did not solve this problem. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this over here. In my case it was caused by a bad stick of RAM. OWC has a good article about checking for bad RAM DIMMs over here: http://eshop.macsales.com/Search/displayFAQDetails.cfm?ID=355 - maybe worth a shot. I re-seated my 2 risers in my Mac Pro, and the simulator is buttery smooth again!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that using shiftkey you can toggle simulator animations slower or faster
pushing down shift for about 2 to 3 seconds toggle simulator to slow/fast animation